# Mosaico template list table not rendering

Tags: mosaico

I'm having an issue with Mosaico template list table rendering.

I can see the AJAX response containing the template data, but the table isn't rendering the data.

Table data request URL /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fapi4

```
[
    {
        "values": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "Test template",
                    "base": "versafix-1",
                    "category_id:label": "Newsletter"
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "val": null
                    },
                    {
                        "val": null
                    },
                    {
                        "val": null
                    },
                    {
                        "val": null,
                        "cssClass": "text-right"
                    }
                ],
                "cssClass": "",
                "key": 1
            }
        ],
        "labels": [],
        "entity": "SearchDisplay",
        "action": "run",
        "debug": null,
        "version": 4,
        "count": 1,
        "countFetched": 1
    }
]
```

[image: table not rendering]

Using WP 6.2, CiviCRM 5.50.4 Mosaico 3.2

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mosaico 3.2 says it requires CiviCRM 5.59 and it looks like you only have 5.50.4, so it seems likely that's a problem as the page you are having trouble with is SearchKit-based, which is an area of CiviCRM that sees quite a bit of active development and would have changed quite a bit between 5.50 and 5.59.

Welcome to CiviCRM, BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response, updated to CiviCRM 5.64 and still seeing the same issue. I was using Mosaico 2.9 with Civi 5.50 and encountered the issue so upgraded Mosaico to 3.2 to try to resolve. So now they are both bang up to date and still see this issue.

Comment: Do other FormBuilder forms work? For example, if you enable the AdminUI extension and go to Administer Profiles?

Comment: Did you install mosaico directly from git or did you use an official download zip file? If the former then you need to run Composer.

Comment: I can confirm other FormBuilder forms work fine, I can see the AJAX data response and the table is populated with that.

Comment: Mosaico was installed from the official download zip.